# Git : fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'origin/release_2.6'

Tags: git, reference

I am getting this error when trying to create a remote tracking branch

```
git co -b release_2.6 origin/release_2.6
warning: refname 'origin/release_2.6' is ambiguous.
warning: refname 'origin/release_2.6' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'origin/release_2.6'.
```

I only have these two refs defined with release_2.6

```
git show-ref | grep "release_2.6"
a71b2da1526f73862464a23aceaa1939a8b1ace2 refs/heads/origin/release_2.6
ed1399936a8cc4cd2feed1851123af861b0ff093 refs/remotes/origin/release_2.6
```

Does anyone know what this error means?

Cheers

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If something can be found in both `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/` then this is ambiguous. 
You have local branch `origin/release_2.6` and remote tracking branch `release_2.6` for remote `origin`. Don't think you are supposed to have a `refs/heads/origin/release_2.6` branch though. Anyway, you can specify full reference name to resolve ambiguity:

```
git co -b release_2.6 refs/remotes/origin/release_2.6
```

Comment: The full ref search path is described in [ *git-rev-parse(1)* in the section “Specifying Revisions”](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions), under the bullet starting “A symbolic ref name. …”.

Comment: Yes i think I added the origin/release_2.6 branch accidentally but did not see it in the list. I deleted that local branch and then it all worked. Thank you!

Comment: Had the same problem when trying to do `git branch --set-upstream-to=...`. Adding `refs/remotes/origin` instead of simply `origin/` worked :) .

Answer (score 15):

I had similar error when I created a remote branch using git-svn. I had the remote branch and the local branch with same name. You can rename the local branch using

`git branch -m old_branch new_name`
This will just rename the local branch without changing the remote branch.

Shravan

Answer (score 8):

For me, it was just a dumb mistake. I accidentally created a branch named like the remote, like in this case I had a local branch like `origin/release_2.6` :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error when I cloned an SVN repository with git-svn, but I had no "origin" in either path.  I ended up with the following refs:

```
 0e4b5116f69200ea0d7a2ff9f0fa15630d02b153 refs/heads/development
 0ef5969f7ee44b16817053bfe146c499be5f77b7 refs/remotes/development
```

and I was unable to branch; when I tried I would get the "ambiguous object name" error.  My error was that when I did the original git svn clone, I did not specify a --prefix; the correct form was

```
git svn clone --prefix origin/ --stdlayout xxxx
```

and then I ended up with refs/remotes/origin/development, etc. and there was no problem branching.  According to the man page, you must have the trailing slash on the prefix.

Liam

Answer (score 3):

I got this error because I had a branch "develop" and a tag called "develop".

```
$ git tag
develop
master
staging
v0.0.1-test
v0.0.11
```

Deleting both the local tag and remote tag matching the branch name worked for me.

```
$ git tag -d develop
$ git push origin :refs/tags/develop
```